# Why MyEclipse is not recognizing project as gradle project?

Tags: gradle, myeclipse, spring-tool-suite, gradle-eclipse

We have a gradle project in SVN and we are checking out that project from SVN into MyEclipse. This project is having build.gradle and settings.graddle along with src which is having project source code. When I right click on build.gradle file gradle build options as are not displaying and we are unable to build from MyEclipse. But, those build options are enabling when we import the project from one of the folder as gradle project after clicking on "build model" option. Can anyone explain why gradle build options are not getting displayed in MyEclipse?

[image: SVN gradle project structure as below -]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saving the project's .project file in SVN? If the project in SVN does not have a .project file, then you will have to check it out as a project using the New Project Wizard and select Gradle/Gradle Project from the list of new project wizards.

If you do have a .project file, check it to make sure it has the gradle project nature.

Comment: Thank you Tony. You saved my time where every time I used checkout in to local folder and importing it as gradle project with build module. Thank you!!!

Comment: Hi Tony,
Can you please tell me what is the gradle project structure to checkin into SVN? As of we have checked into SVN as mentioned in the above screen, what else need to add to become standard folder structure? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Gradle but once you have a Gradle project in MyEclipse, you should make sure that the ".project" and ".classpath" files, and the ".settings" folder are all shared in SVN. By default, those files and folders won't be ignored so, if they are being ignored when shared in SVN, then they may have been added to the list seen in Window->Preferences->Team->Ignored Resources. I don't know what specific files and folders are needed for Gradle projects, just make sure that anything that is ignored isn't needed for the project to be imported properly as a Gradle project.